# When to use singular or plural for countable words?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, countable-nouns, singular

Main point is regarding the last sentence about the avocado. Here is an example:

"A long time ago sushi was not popular to Westerners because they did not like to eat raw fish. Alternatively, Japanese chefs created the California roll. So some Japanese chefs used avocado."

vs.

"A long time ago sushi was not popular to Westerners because they did not like to eat raw fish. Alternatively, Japanese chefs created the California roll. So some Japanese chefs used avocados."

Which one is correct (avocado/avocados) and why?

Comment: sushi was not popular _with_ or _among_ Westerners

Comment: As an alternative, Japanese chefs...

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Why "So"? Are you saying they used avocados because the California roll had been invented? By the way, you don't need to repeat 'Japanese chefs'.

Comment: I had to look up what a California roll is, but it appears to use pieces of avocado flesh, not whole fruits. So I would use _avocado_ (meaning the substance).